# Evaluate $f(x)$ where $f(x)=\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}$ and $x=0.00275$

Tags: numerical-methods

So all that need to be done is to find the bounded error and add it to $f(0.00275)$?

So we take the derivative of $$\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}, f'(x)=\frac{x^2e^{-x-1}-1+e^{-x}}{x^2}$$ now we find $\Delta x=0.5*10^{-5}$

So $$|\frac{(0.00275)^2e^{-0.00275)-1}-1+e^{-0.00275)}}{0.00275)^2}*(0.5*10^{-5})|=0.66296$$

So the answer is: $$\frac{1-e^{-(0.00275)}}{(0.00275)}\pm 0.66296=0.99862\pm 0.66296$$

?

Comment: To answer that the desired value is between $0.33$ and $1.66$ is rather terrible, no? Instead, use $$e^{-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^n}{n!}$$ hence $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}$$ which, implies, for example, $$f(x)=1-\frac{x}2+\frac{x^2}6-g(x)$$ with, at least for every $x$ in $(0,1)$, $$0<g(x)<\frac{x^3}{24}$$ For $x=0.00275$, this yields an error bounded by $10^{-9}$. Using only $$f(x)=1-\frac{x}2+h(x)$$ with $$0<h(x)<\frac{x^2}{6}$$ yields, again for $x=0.00275$, an error bounded by $1.3\cdot10^{-6}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need all these computations. Start from the power series expansion of $\mathrm e^{-x}=1-x+\dfrac{x^2}2-\dfrac{x^3}6+\dotsm$. For $0<x<1$, this is an alternating series and, by Leibniz' rule the absolute value of error when we take the expansion up to degree $k$ is less than $\dfrac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$, and the error has the same sign.

Suppose we take the quadratic approximation. We then have
$$x-\frac{x^2}2<1-\mathrm e^{-x}<x,\quad\text{whence}\quad 1-\frac x2<f(x)<1.$$
Numerically: $\qquad0.997\,25<f(0.002\,75)<1.000\,00$.

Comment: "Alternating" only if $0<x<1$.

Comment: @Did: Why $x<1 $?

Comment: Because otherwise this is not an alternating series (recall that the successive terms of an alternating series must alternate signs *and also decrease in absolute value*).

Comment: @Did: Oh! yes. I had forgotten  this hypothesis (which is satisfied in practice). I've fixed my answer. Thanks for pointing it